# Exporting FinancialInstrument:::.instrument to foreach workers and unpacking it

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, financialinstrument

I am doing some parallel processing and need to access instrument properties from `FinancialInstrument:::.instrument` environment at each worker spawned by parallel processing.

Simple `instrument.list <- as.list(FinancialInstrument:::.instrument)` and using `.export` argument with `foreach` does not work (as the code below shows it works when no parallel backends are registered and does not when they are). Please see reproducible example below:

```
library(FinancialInstrument)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

currency(c("USD", "EUR")) # define some currencies
stock(c("SPY", "LQD", "IBM", "GS"), currency="USD") # define some stocks
exchange_rate("EURUSD") # define an exchange rate

ls_stocks() #get the names of all the stocks
ls_instruments() # all instruments

getInstrument("IBM")

instrument.list <- as.list(FinancialInstrument:::.instrument)

# First let's run this without parallel backend registered to show the code works
foreach(1:2,
        .packages="FinancialInstrument",
        .export="instrument.list"
        ) %dopar% {
            .instrument <- as.environment(instrument.list)
            message(paste0("Available instruments in .instrument environment: ", paste(ls_instruments(), collapse=", "), " ."))
        }


# Now, let's register a parallel backend
cl <- makeCluster(2, outfile="log.txt")
registerDoParallel(cl)

# And by looking in log.txt file we see that .instrument environment is not functioning properly. How to make this work?
foreach(1:2,
        .packages="FinancialInstrument",
        .export="instrument.list"
        ) %dopar% {
            .instrument <- as.environment(instrument.list)
            message(paste0("Available instruments in .instrument environment: ", paste(ls_instruments(), collapse=", "), " ."))
        }

stopCluster(cl)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working using assignInNamespace function in worker. Below is now a working code from the question above:

```
library(FinancialInstrument)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

currency(c("USD", "EUR")) # define some currencies
stock(c("SPY", "LQD", "IBM", "GS"), currency="USD") # define some stocks
exchange_rate("EURUSD") # define an exchange rate

ls_stocks() #get the names of all the stocks
ls_instruments() # all instruments

getInstrument("IBM")

instrument.list <- as.list(FinancialInstrument:::.instrument)

# First let's run this without parallel backend registered to show the code works
foreach(1:2,
        .packages="FinancialInstrument",
        .export="instrument.list"
        ) %dopar% {
            .instrument <- as.environment(instrument.list)
            message(paste0("Available instruments in .instrument environment: ", paste(ls_instruments(), collapse=", "), " ."))
        }


# Now, let's register a parallel backend
cl <- makeCluster(2, outfile="log.txt")
registerDoParallel(cl)

# And by looking in log.txt file we see that .instrument environment is not functioning properly. How to make this work?
foreach(1:2,
        .packages="FinancialInstrument",
        .export="instrument.list"
        ) %dopar% {
            assignInNamespace(".instrument", as.environment(instrument.list), "FinancialInstrument")
            message(paste0("Available instruments in .instrument environment: ", paste(ls_instruments(), collapse=", "), " ."))
        }

stopCluster(cl)
```